# Image processing and object detection in sales force automation

Tags: image-processing, python

We have a specific requirement in our sales force automation product.

---

**Requirement in merchandising module** 
There is one shelf check activity in merchandising where salesman is capturing which products are available in shelf and how many quantity is available , so he can replenish remaining quantity.

Now we want to automate this process where salesman can capture image of shelf and we want to do image processing where it will check which products are available in shelf and how many quantity available.

---

**We found below 2 ways by which it can be achieved**

```
 - Image Processing though OpenCV in android
 - Image Processing through back end using python which we will send image to 
   server after capturing for image processing
```

Please suggest me which way is better to proceed

Regards,
Bindal

Comment: I think the question of whether to do something on a phone or on a backend these days should only be answered once you understand the computational and data needs of your algorithm. So, do you have a working implementation of the system you propose already? Then you can make judgement on which parts of it to compute where.

Comment: Please don't  [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370275/image-processing-and-object-detection-in-sales-force-automation) without telling any one.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : I am starting on this work by research or hiring freelancers for this i am newbie on this thats why  i am asking here to experts like you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : i have posted here , because i thought stack overflow is only for coding related, this site is more of theoratical questions answers . if you want i will remove from there, thanks

Comment: yes, but you're not asking a *signal processing* question, but a fundamental system design question that we can't answer without knowing how complex the thing is you want to do. So, we can't help you.